# Setting target method of a button to a function from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that fetches photos info from facebook. I try to abstract it by adding it to another class and setting target function of the button to that class function.

So I have a singleton class

```
class FacebookManager  {

static let sharedInstance = FacebookManager()

func getAlbums() {

    var request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/\(facebookID!)/albums", parameters: ["fields": "cover_photo, name, description"])
    request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        // do stuff
    })

}
```

and a method in viewcontroller for button that calls that function

```
dummyButton?.addTarget(FacebookManager.self, action: Selector("getAlbums"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

but after tapping on button I get an error

> 2016-08-17 00:12:21.599 Lovrr[11807:3832289] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x10717c888 of class 'app.FacebookManager' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector +[app.FacebookManager getAlbums]

in some topic in stackoverflow I saw an advice of subclassing `NSObject` in FacebookManager. After doing this I get another error

> [app.FacebookManager getAlbums]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1047026f0
>   2016-08-17 00:13:49.469 app[11892:3834005] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[app.FacebookManager getAlbums]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1047026f0'

How to do what I want properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target is wrong:

```
dummyButton?.addTarget(FacebookManager.self, action: Selector("getAlbums"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

`FacebookManager.self` means static level. `getAlbums` is a class method. =>
**unrecognized selector**

Fix with:

```
dummyButton?.addTarget(FacebookManager.sharedInstance, action: Selector("getAlbums"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, however, this solution is not working for me